apple-touch-icon without the sizes attr
Is there a reason why MDN Docs and Apple's documentation on configuring web list one of the link elements for apple-touch-icon without the sizes attribute?
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">


<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">

And why the link element with sizes="180x180" lies in the middle of the code in these websites? Is there anything that I'm missing?
Didn't try anything.

The sizes attribute is optional in  element for apple-touch-icon.
Without it, the device uses the default or most suitable icon.
The order of these elements in the HTML is based on the developer's preference or specific requirements, so there's nothing wrong with the sizes="180x180" link being in the middle.
